# Regarding the order of AR and MA terms in ARMA

Tags: time-series

I want to run ARMA model on residuals of a time series. The series is stationary. ACF and PACF plots are both significant at second lag. It means I should use ARMA(2,2) model.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autocorrelation can often be induced by the (untreated) presence of deterministic structure i.e. seasonal pulses in the data OR possible transience of model parameters over time. Post your ORIGINAL data and I will try and be of more help.

[image]

As suggested the "appearance of significiant acf structure " reflects underlying causal structure ... i.e. monthly effects suggesting certain months-of-the-year exhibit predictable behavior NOT MEMORY.

Comment: I am mailing you residual series of my model

Comment: You should also send the original series as you may have INJECTED structure . Unwarranted transformations of all kinds ( differencing , arima filters , logs  et al ) can  have unexpected consequences particularly self-cancelling ARIMA models such as 2,0,2 when no filter is required.

Comment: thanks sir you are right. I got the point